# ¿Como generar reporte PDF en Datatable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

alguno sabra como puedo generar reportes PDF en datatable,sin utilizar los buttons predefinidos de Printhtml5, Excel, que ofrece datatable? Estoy utilizando MVC, C#

Comment: por que no quieres usar el reporte de datatable?

Comment: 1)Le soy sincero no se cuales son las diferencias utilizando los de datatable y hacerlo manualmente... 2) tengo dos botones de mi vista hasta la parte de abajo y por lo que intente, cambie de posicion con el DOM los botones pero no queda justo donde yo quiero... habra manera de poner la funcion de los botones de datatable en otros botones distintos?

Comment: si no usas server-side para tu data table creo que lo mas sencillo es usar el reporte de datatable ya que el reporte será de todos los datos que estén en el datatable, y los botones puedes personalizarlos y moverlos donde mas te convenga dentro del espacio del datatable ya que si usas botones externos estos estarán fuera de dicho espacio lo que hará que no se vea muy estético

Comment: Tendras alguna recomendacion de algun tutorial o algo por el estilo, para poder saber como hacer el llamado de mi tabla de datatable, y ponerla dentro de cierto codigo que hara que genere el pdf?

Comment: lo siento no tengo esa información

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es una tabla que tengo con data table si te sirve

```
$("#table_id").DataTable({
        "processing": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 370,
        "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12 float-right'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
        "buttons": [
            {
                extend: 'print', title: "Marcaciones", titleAttr: 'Imprimir', text: '<i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>', className: 'btn btn-secondary', exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                }, customize: function (win) {
                    $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                    $(win.document.body).find('h1').css('text-align', 'center');
                    $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '9px');
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf', titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF', text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i>', className: 'btn btn-danger', exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
                /*Centra la tabla del PDF
                 * customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.content[1].margin = [100, 0, 100, 0] //left, top, right, bottom
                }*/
            },
            { extend: 'excel', titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel', text: '<i class= "fa fa-file-excel" aria-hidden="true"></i>', className: 'btn btn-success', exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] } }
        ],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "url",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "data": null,
        "order": [[1, "desc"]],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "accion", "name": "accion"},
            { "data": "fechaHoraString", "name": "fecha" },
            { "data": "nombreResponsable", "name": "nombreResponsable"},
            { "data": "nombreImplicado", "name": "nombreImplicado" },
            { "data": "tipoImplicadoString", "name": "tipoImplicado" },
            { "data": "detalle", "name": "detalle"},
            { "data": "tipoString", "name": "tipo" },
        ],
    });
```

Comment: Henry... que amable, podrias indicarme unicamente tu codigo de como pusiste los 3 botones al lado derecho?

Comment: esa parte se configura en "dom" del data table

Comment: para la parte de los botones lo estoy configurando para que este elemento este primero y que este dentro de un div con las clases  col-md-12 y float-right lo que hará que ocupe todo el ancho y se alinee a la derecha ( <'col-md-12 float-right'B> ) la letra B  representa a los botones en el DT

Comment: Aqui algunos enlaces que te ayudaran a comprender mejor https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html,   https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons